# Paginación con enlistador o checkbox mostrar todo

Tags: php, mysql

hola me gustaría agregar una de estas dos herramientas, un enlistador o un checkbox para mi proyecto pero la verdad no tengo ni idea como empezar, por favor agradecería su ayuda mucho dejo imagen de lo que me gustaria realizar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo el código que estoy utilizando para mi paginador

```
<?php 
              //PAGINADOR

            $sql_registe = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM usuarios WHERE estatus=1"); 
           $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registe);
           $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];

           $por_pagina = 12;
           if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) 
           {
              $pagina = 1;
           }else{
            $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
           }

           $desde =($pagina-1) * $por_pagina;
           $total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_pagina);

          $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT u.idUsuarios, u.Nombres, u.Apellidos, s.Sexo, u.FechaNacimiento, u.Usuario, u.CorreoElectronico, r.Roles FROM usuarios u INNER JOIN rol r ON u.rol = r.idRol INNER JOIN sexo s ON u.Sexo = s.idSexo WHERE estatus = 1 
              ORDER BY u.idUsuarios ASC
              LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina");

           mysqli_close($conection);

          $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);
          if ($result > 0) {

            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
          ?>
```

Comment: Hola, la verdad es que creo no me di a entender, lo único que que quiero es, cuando to active el checkbox muestre todos mis registros, y cuando este desactivado el checkbox solo me muestre 12 (ejemplo) pero la verdad no se como hacerlo, no se si me explique?

Comment: Acabo de ampliar la respuesta, ya me confirmas si te referías a lo que te he respondido. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Por el aspecto que tiene tu código, parece que quieres hacer la paginación en el backend, en tu PHP. De hecho, hasta parece que ya tienes preparado tu código para recibir un `$_GET['pagina']` con la próxima página a visualizar. Es decir, que sólo tienes que añadir un enlace o un formulario como el indicas en la pregunta.

```
echo '<a href="?pagina='.($pagina+1).'"> > </a>';
```

Como alternativa, te propondría realizar ese trabajo en front: enviarle todos los datos al cliente, si no es una cantidad ingente, y dejarle el trabajo de visualización a éste. Así no tendrás que recargar el resto de la página web cada vez que quieras ver un nuevo grupo de datos (a lo que te refieres como página). Para ello ya tendrías que programar en JS.

Modifica tu pregunta con tus dudas, intentos y mensajes de error que recibas y, con gusto, ampliaré mi respuesta para que puedas alcanzar tu objetivo.

### Ampliación de respuesta

Por lo que comentas bajo la pregunta, en tu formulario tendrás que incluir ese campo checkbox y condicionar el `LIMIT` a que el usuario lo valide o no:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="todo"> Mostrar todo
<button>Consultar</button>
</form>

<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');

$sql="SELECT * FROM usuario";

if(!isset($_GET['todo']) or $_GET['todo']!='on')
    $sql.=" LIMIT 15";

$r=$conn->query($sql)->fetch_all();

echo count($r);
```

Comment: Este código es completamente independiente del paginador o tengo que corregir ambos ?, una disculpa de ante mano si soy algo molesto por mi ignorancia :(

Comment: Hola @juan21, este código es un ejemplo de cómo tienes que modificar tu código para que funcione como esperas. No es un código que puedas pegar en el tuyo para que pagine. Te estoy mostrando el camino, no haciendo tu trabajo. Intenta entender los pasos que doy para después darlos tú. Pregunta todo lo que necesites :)